# In Docker how to create and container with rabbitmq , mysql and zookeeper , Can someone give the exact command for it?

Tags: mysql, docker, rabbitmq, apache-zookeeper

In Docker how to create and container with rabbitmq , mysql and zookeeper , Can someone give the exact command for it ??

Comment: That's not really what docker is meant for. You'd generally have one container for rabbitmq, one for mysql and another for zookeeper. One (main) process per container. If you want them all in one, perhaps a standard VM setup would be more appropriate.

Comment: yeah i agree you are right . i just tried with the couple of commands it fails, can you give me the command for it ??.

Comment: Command for what? Putting them all in the same container? I can't answer that, there are too many variables.

Comment: Not for Putting them all in the same container . Command for starting it in the separate container

Comment: Go for Docker Compose like pointed out in answer below. There you can specify all containers that you need in your environment + there configuration + ports they should expose or need to interact with each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an "exact command" for this - you'll be running three different containers, and you'll want them to communicate, and there are lots of ways of doing that in Docker.

These apps all have official images on the Docker Hub with good documentation:

- [Zookeeper](https://hub.docker.com/_/zookeeper/)
- [RabbitMQ](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/)
- [MySQL](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)

Using [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) to manage the containers as one unit would be a good place to start.